# Does the Chef package resource require a separate download step?

Tags: chef-infra

Does a package need to be downloaded to the Chef server fist before it can be installed on nodes or is it sufficient to create a recipe that installs the pacakge and Chef will take care of downloading the package prior to its installation?

Answer (score 2):

The chef-server is only used to manage cookbooks, roles, and other similar data. It is not involved in actually converging the node configuration. With packages, Chef just calls the relevant `apt`/`yum`/etc command exactly as you would by hand.

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://docs.getchef.com/resource_package.html) sys:

> Use the **package** resource to manage packages. When the package is installed from a local file (such as with RubyGems, dpkg, or RPM Package Manager), the file must be added to the node using the **remote_file** or **cookbook_file** resources.

Thus -- it depends on the provider for the resource. If your provider is, say, yum or apt, that will handle the download itself; if the provider is, say, RubyGems, you'll need to do the download yourself.

In any of these cases, however, the download required is to the *client*, not the Chef *server*.

Comment: In no configuration do you have to do the download to the *chef server*.

Comment: ...ahh -- it's put in the question. Clarified.